# After upgrading to 14.04 my dropbox notifier is missing

Tags: 14.04, dropbox

Reinstalling lippappindicator1 doesn't help. I'm using dropbox 1.6.1-1. Under 13.10 everything was fine. I'm not sure whether syncing is working.

Comment: What is the output of `dropbox status`? Can you create a file in your Dropbox, then go to the web interface to see if it shows up?

Comment: Good question. No, it doesn't. Sync doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling `nautilus-dropbox`?

Comment: Yes, I reinstalled nautilus-dropbox. Actually this didn't changed anything.

Comment: What does `dropbox status` say?

Comment: dropbox isn't running.

Comment: with `dropbox start` I get lots of traceback errors.

Comment: In some cases it has helped to uninstall nautilus-dropbox and install the version that Dropbox provides on their website. If that doesn't work, I recommend reporting this as a bug.

Comment: FWIW, mine is working on 14.04.  I usually start it from the command line with `dropbox start` . It took longer than expected for the notifier to show up, but it did.

Answer (score 3):

A solution can be found in [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/01/fix-dropbox-fails-to-start-with.html).

> To fix this Dropbox error in Ubuntu / Linux Mint / Debian, open a terminal and run the following commands:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dropbox/.dropbox-dist
dropbox start -i
```

It worked perfectly for me!

Comment: Providing a bit more detail than just a link would be preferred.