# Dropbox 3.2.9 ignoring local themes / missing notification icon

Tags: 14.04, themes, icons, dropbox

After upgrading from xubuntu 13.10 to 14.04, I found that dropbox needed re-installation on my system, amongst a slew of other problems. I performed the following as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/461866/76314):

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dropbox/.dropbox-dist
dropbox start -i
```

**EDIT:** as this had failed to resolve the problem described below, I have also tried to install Dropbox from the `.deb` from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx) for Ubuntu.

This has installed dropbox version 3.2.9 which appears to be working again, however the notifier icon in the `xfce4-panel` does not abide by the locally set theme/icons:

[image: dropbox icon not abiding by elementary-xfce-dark theme]

Here, I am using `elementary-xfce-dark`, and can confirm that the Dropbox status icons I want to use are present in `/usr/share/icons/elementary-xfce-dark/panel`.

However, the icons actually being used (`~/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-3.2.9/images/hicolor/16x16/status`) are PNG files with transparency, however on inspection the background is `#EFEBE7`, which suggests the alpha channel is being used, and something else is setting this as the background color.

***UPDATE***

On occasion, the Dropbox icon doesn't appear in the `xfce4-panel` at all after a reboot, either in the notification area, or the system tray.

***PARTLY RESOLVED***

So, err, after purging then re-installing Dropbox from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx) using the .deb package, I now intermittently see this after each hard reboot:

[image: Correctly using background color with Dropbox icon image]

Here's a list of everything I can remember I did before the hard reboot:

- Installed the following:

  - libappindicator1 (tried because of [these](https://askubuntu.com/questions/358913/no-dropbox-icon-in-the-indicator-panel) [tips](http://itsfoss.com/solve-dropbox-icon-ubuntu-1310/), found it was already installed);
  - libappindicator3-1 (was not already installed)
  - libappindicator3-dev (was not already installed)
- Followed the tip from [here](https://pseudomorph.wordpress.com/2014/05/08/xfce-notification-a/) which disables auto-start of the `indicator-application-service` at login (called 'Indicator Application' in the 'Session and Startup'/'Application Autostart' menu);
- [Sacrificed several goats](http://37.media.tumblr.com/6f2e724744469cb0e0fe2f612a1909fa/tumblr_n2ube1AQJQ1tq4of6o1_250.gif).

I can confirm that:

- The running version is being invoked from `~/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-3.2.9/`;
- The dropbox icon appears in the **notification area**, not the system tray, of the `xfce4-panel`;
- `$ python --version` produces `Python 2.7.6`

I'm uncertain as to precisely which, if any, of the above steps were necessary to affect the appearance of the icon. Again, disappointingly, the icon only appears intermittently -- once out of every few shutdown/boot cycles, so YMMV!

I also note that when it is present, the icon(s) and theme/style being used are still not consistent with the locally set theme. For example, check out the tooltips :

[image: dropbox 3.0.3 tooltip not using local theme] ...versus... [image: bluetooth notification area icon using local theme]

---

***PROGRESS NOTES***

- There appears to be chatter about this problem [here](http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=38154), and [here](https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/communities/public/questions/201269689-tray-icon-linux), suggesting that the latest version of dropbox (3.0.3) now uses the [Qt UI](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/07/dropbox-ui-rewritten-in-qt-for-latest.html). The behavior of dropbox 3.0.3 to ignore local themes also seems to apply to other linux distributions such as [Mint](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=190&p=957544) and [Arch](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/dropbox).
- [This page](https://forum.manjaro.org/index.php?topic=13728) suggests that xfce4 had a bug which did not permit Qt5 software from using the local theme. However, upgrading to `xfce4-session` version 4.11 has not solved the problem.
- I'm about to embark on a fresh install of xubuntu 14.0.4-1 to address other issues, so I'll report back here as to whether the problem persists.
- After installing a fresh version of xubuntu 14.04-1, I now see no dropbox notification icon at all! I presume that if I find a way of activating it again, I might still have the same problem. I'll keep on it...
- Trying out various installation options (deb files from the dropbox website, compiling and installing from source) has not yielded any solution yet. Suggestions welcome!

Comment: Thanks @DKBose -- I've already done that (copied over the right icons) -- but I'd like it to use the local theme to avoid the white background, too. I'm now suspecting this is a bug with the latest release (3.0.3).

Comment: Same issue here. To be frank, I've gotten quite annoyed with Dropbox' antics lately. The daemon has a pretty significant performance and memory footprint on my system. Add to this these new cosmetic issues and I think I am done with autostarting Dropbox. If you are looking for a different solution check out [this dropbox sync script](http://askubuntu.com/a/349865). You can use it to perform a one-time sync. No need to have the ugly daemon running permanently.

Answer (score 6):

So, no complete answer in over two months?

[image]
***Allllllll-righty then!***

Now presenting... my ever-so-embarrassing, not-really-to-be-recommended, disgustingly cringeworthy **hack**:

- Find your notification icons in the `.dropbox-dist` directory, which might be in `~/.dropbox-dist` or `/var/lib/dropbox/.dropbox-dist`. Inside this, the icons are in the folder `dropbox-lnx.x86_64-3.2.9/images/hicolor/16x16/status` (or similar, your path may differ depending on the version and build used).
- Determine the colour of your `xfce4-panel`. This is easy using a tool like [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/) with the colour picker tool ([image]). Mine happens to be `#242424`.
- For each of the notification icons which are PNG images with transparency, open them with Gimp. Yes, that's right folks, I'm going to *change that background from transparent to a solid color* (in my case, `#242424`). [image: *Hangs head in shame.*]

The result:

[image]

[image]

Looking good. This is perfectly fine for me, as I don't change the `xfce4-panel` color. However, some things to note:

- You'll need to restart dropbox for the change to take effect:

  - ~$ dropbox stop
  - ~$ dropbox start
- If you edit the stock 16x16px icons, you might find them centred with a 2px `#EFEBE7` border if your icons are 22x22px. I addressed this by simply enlarging the icons to my required size (22x22px).
- If Dropbox is ever updated, your icons might be blown away. If you're going to try this yourself, keep a backup copy of your icons outside the Dropbox directory. Or, you can just download them from here (if you also use `#242424` for your panel color):
- [image: dropboxstatus-logo.png] (`dropboxstatus-logo.png`)
- [image: dropboxstatus-idle.png] (`dropboxstatus-idle.png`)
- [image: dropboxstatus-busy.png] (`dropboxstatus-busy.png`)
- [image: dropboxstatus-busy2.png] (`dropboxstatus-busy2.png`)
- [image: dropboxstatus-x.png] (`dropboxstatus-x.png`)

Comment: Instead of manually adjusting each image you can use the command `for i in *.png; do convert $i -background '#000000' -alpha remove $i; done` replacing `#000000` with the correct color code for your panel. Note that this overwrites the images, so you may want to back up the icons first!

Comment: @LaurenceGonsalves sweeeet.

Comment: This solution is ok I used it to change the white areas to a darker color, but then when dropbox is updated it changes the images back. It's very annoying specially because IT'S IMPOSSIBLE TO PREVENT DROPBOX TRAY ICON CRA*PY PROGRAM FROM UPDATING. Why is that? Because you don't even have the freedom to use the program. That's why I love Free Software! I use dropbox because of some work reasons that cannot be avoided (I hate to be forced to use it).

Answer (score 5):

If you disable compositing and then do a restart, the icon shows up in the tray bar. Sadly, that's not a solution for me, as I need compositing.

To disable compositing in Xubuntu 14.04:

- Go to "All settings" and click on "Window manager tweaks":

[image]

- Go to the tab "Compositor"
- Uncheck the "Enable display compositing" option

[image]

PS: I should've probably added this in the comments instead, but I cannot comment yet, not enough rep. points (stupid rule).

Comment: Hopefully someone can use this to create a real solution!

Comment: Cool, thanks. Disabling compositing reveals the Dropbox icon, but on my machine it still isn't abiding by the locally set theme, and looks like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/M3tTB.png). At least I can now access the context menu where I couldn't before!

Answer (score 1):

This is an automated version of sharky's answer. First, create a script called `fix-dropbox-icons`:

```
#!/bin/bash
find $HOME/.dropbox-dist/ -name '*.png' -exec \
    convert \{} -background '#000000' -alpha remove \{} \;
```

If your background is some color other than black then adcjust the `#000000` bit accordingly. Don't forget to `chmod +x` this script.

In your startup (`.xsession`, `.Xinit`, `.i3/config`, DE settings... depends on your setup) make it run this script at startup/login. If dropbox updates and restarts while you're logged in the icon will be temporarily messed up, but the next time you log in it should be fixed again.

Answer (score -1):

in mint17.1 I uninstalled dropbox and installe Nemo Dropbox in synaptic and the icon showed up in the system tray, on using these keys on the keyboard  ctrl, alt, back space -  to reset

Answer (score -1):

XUBUNTU 14.04.1 kernel 3.13.0-44

I used the bash -c "dropbox stop && sleep 5 && strace ~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd 2>/dev/null >/dev/null" script above and it restored the notification icon. However, it disappeared again when I closed the terminal or broke out using CTRL-C.

I put the script in my startup programs with the -D switch and rebooted. Now, the icon shows up permanently.

bash -c "dropbox stop && sleep 5 && strace -D ~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd 2>/dev/null >/dev/null"

Hope this helps...

Answer (score -1):

This is how I completely solved after many attempts. I hope it will be usefull also for someone else:

- uninstalled dropbox from applications manager
- deleted the dropbox-automatic-boot line into settings/session-start
- disabled composite manager (by uchecking its box)
- rebooted
- re-installed dropbox from the terminal:

  ```
  cd ~ && wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86_64" | tar xzf -
  ```
- manually created a new dropbox-automatic-boot line into settings/session-start with this new path:

  ```
  /home/my_home/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-3.2.6/dropbox
  ```
- rebooted and eventually re-enabled composite manager

Comment: Does this fix the issue with the icon not abiding by local themes?

Answer (score -2):

The compositing thing works erratically for me, without doing a restart. If you keep clicking the enable/disable checkbox sometimes it reappears.